# Limiting behaviour between ratio $q$-Pochhammer symbol and $n$'th coefficient

Tags: limits, pochhammer-symbol

Is there a a simple expression for the following limit,

$$t(a, q) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{a^n q^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}}{\left(a;q\right)_n} .$$

The denominator $\left(a; q\right)_n$ is the $q$-Pochhammer symbol, and the numerator corresponds to the norm of the $n$'th coefficient of the expansion of $\left(a;q\right)_n$. The question arised from investigating the asymptotic behaviour of a combinatorial formula, and $t(a, q)$ is the scaling factor. I am particularly interested in the case $a=q$.

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"? Do you have a guess?

Comment: No guess (yet). I would be content with anything that would fall under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression .

Comment: A quick test seems to strongly suggest that the limit is zero if $\,0<a<1\,$ and $\,0<q<1.$